# How to solve Expected identifier error in c?

Tags: c

I am building my own game engine .... and I came across this error:

`error: expected identifier or '('`

here's the code:

```
#define RX_ASSERT(expr )
    { 
        if {(expr)}{

        }
        else
        {
            report_assertion_failure(#expr, "", __FILE__, __LINE__);
            debugBreak();
        }
    }

#define RX_ASSERT_MSG(expr, message )
    { 
        if {expr}{

        }
        else
        {
            report_assertion_failure(#expr, message, __FILE__, __LINE__);
            debugBreak();
        }
    }
```

I tried to compile this in Clang, but it failed :(

Comment: `if {expr}` is invalid syntax.

Comment: If those are meant to be two macros, then you need to end all lines except the last with a backslash.  Otherwise, if that appears outside a function, it is syntactically invalid.  And the `if {expr}` comment from @Alexander is completely valid, whether this is meant to be two macros or not.  You might be meaning `if (!(expr))` which eliminates the need for an empty statement after the `if` — you'd place your current `else` clause as the body of the `if`.  See also [Why use apparently meaningless `do`/`while` and `if`/`else` statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154136/15168)